# How should I do query

Tags: laravel

I was using data table template for frontend. It already have per page and pagination and search. So, how should I do for query. I did like this. I also wanna use search and paginate from template datatable.

```
public function index() 
{
    $users = User::all();

    return view('users.list', compact('users'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the laravel built-in pagination:

```php
public function index() 
{
   $users = User::paginate(15);

   return view('users.list', compact('users'));
}
```

Then in your view you can loop through your user list and use the pagination links like this:

`{{ $users->links() }}`

Comment: I wanna use build in pagination  and search from data table. so what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

You should customised your code to do so and here you go:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->query('search');

    $customers = customers::where('name', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->paginate(10);

    return view('App.Customer.customerList', compact('customers'));
}
```

Comment: where did you get that this user is using `App.Customer.customerList` or `customers` model, etc? He/she never mentioned that

Comment: I wanna use build in pagination and search from data table. so what should I do?